# Openlayers 5 Darken the Map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-5

I want to have a dark map just like in the photo in order to make the other features inside the other layers more visible.
What is the best approach to achieving this?

```
  map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM({
          wrapX: false
        })
      }),
      trackLayer,
      circleMarkerLayer,
      missionLayer,
      planeLayer,
      vesselLayer
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attributionOptions: {
        collapsible: false
      },
      attribution: false
    }),
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    view: view
  });
```

[image: Result example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [ol-ext lib](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext) to apply color filters on layers.
See example online: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/filter/map.filter.colorize.html
[image: coloris filter]

Answer (score 2):

You can apply global composite operations at the base layer's postrender event to apply grayscale and other effects (note that the latest version of Chrome has a problem with this).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<table><tr>
<th>Gray</th><th>Intensity</th>
</tr><tr>
<td><input id="gray" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50"></td>
<td><input id="intensity" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="128"></td>
</tr></table>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers : [ 
        new ol.layer.Tile({source : new ol.source.OSM()}),
    ],
    target : 'map',
    logo: false,
    controls: ol.control.defaults({ attributionOptions: { collapsible: false } }),
    view : new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([12.5, 55.7]),
        zoom: 7
    })
});

var intensityInput = document.getElementById('intensity');
var background = 255 - intensityInput.value;

intensityInput.onchange = function() {
    background = 255 - intensityInput.value;
    map.render();
};

var grayInput = document.getElementById('gray');
grayInput.onchange = function() {
    map.render();
};

map.getLayers().getArray()[0].on('postcompose', function (evt) {
    evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'color';
    evt.context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + grayInput.value/100 + ')';
    evt.context.fillRect(0, 0, evt.context.canvas.width, evt.context.canvas.height);
    evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'overlay';
    evt.context.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + [background,background,background].toString() + ')';
    evt.context.fillRect(0, 0, evt.context.canvas.width, evt.context.canvas.height);
    evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, I want to darken the map.

Comment: There are many different global composite operations you could use.Try  `evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';    evt.context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0,' + grayInput.value/100 + ')';`

Comment: @Mike is there any way to grayscale the map but markers?