# Canvas fillstyle to make background blacker

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, openlayers

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/StuckDuckF/pen/oNEYPQg) of a simple OpenLayers map with an example overlay. My goal is to have essentially a dark mode OSM layer. I am currently using [Mr. Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63829180/openlayers-5-darken-the-map/63829923#63829923) but am not quite there to match [MapBox's contrast](https://www.mapbox.com/maps/dark). I would love for a `canvas` wizard to help me with the styling of my map canvas in order to increase contrast but retain the topography markers.

##### Edit: This only works for OpenLayers 3 and I am currently trying to get the same result in OpenLayers 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten acceptably close by using the following function on the basemap (OSM) `postcompose` event :

```js
map.getLayers().getArray()[0].on('postcompose', function (evt) {
    evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'color';
    evt.context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,' + 1.0 + ')';
    evt.context.fillRect(0, 0, evt.context.canvas.width, evt.context.canvas.height);
    evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'overlay';
    evt.context.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + [200,200,200].toString() + ')';
    evt.context.fillRect(0, 0, evt.context.canvas.width, evt.context.canvas.height);
    evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    document.querySelector('canvas').style.filter="invert(99%)";
});
```

Which results in a dark OSM basemap. I am still hoping a `canvas wizard would improve my answer in performance, conciseness and clarity, but here is an example of what the resulting map looks like with an example layer.
[image]